# Handling ties in multiple grepl statements

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I'm working on an assignment where I need to clear a lot of messy string data.
I've worked my way with most problems but got stuck with two problems:

1. Ties when using multiple grepl statements
2. Lot's of code, that I feel, could be simplified but I can't figure out how

Let's consider this minimal example:

`names` is a character vector storing names of 3 distinct persons, written in various ways

`names` should be simplified (recoded) so that multiple occurrences of a person name are stored the same way

Let's assume Johnatan is First John,
Johnnie and johnnie are all Second John,
John, John D., John Doe are Third John.

With my limited `R` knowledge I came this solution:

```
names <- c("John", "Johnatan", "Johnnie", "John D.", "John Doe", "johnnie")

names[grepl("johna", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "First John"
names[grepl("johnn", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Second John"
names[grepl("john d*", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Third John"
```

At this point there is `john` that I have no idea how to recode into `Third John` as

```
names[grepl("john", names, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

will pick up all the john's in `names`.

## Question:

How can I approach this kind of ties, hopefully in a way, more elegant then what I wrote so far?

Thank you for any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary (`\\b`) for `"john"`:

```
names <- c("John", "Johnatan", "Johnnie", "John D.", "John Doe", "johnnie")
names2 = names

names2[grepl("johna", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "First John"
names2[grepl("johnn", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Second John"
names2[grepl("john(\\b|\\sd.*)", names, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Third John"
```

or with `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
names = case_when(grepl("johna", names, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "First Join",
                  grepl("johnn", names, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Second Join",
                  grepl("john(\\b|\\sd.*)", names, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Third Join")
```

**Note:**

- `\\b` matches a word boundary, which could be either a space or punctuation. for example `johnatan` would not be matched since `john` follows another letter `a`, not a word boundary.
- `\\s` matches a space.
- `d.*` matches `d` followed by anything (`.`) zero of more times.
- `( | )` is a capture group that matches either the left hand side or right hand side of `|`.
- `john(\\b|\\sd.*)` matches `john` followed by either a word boundary or a space followed by a `d` and anything zero or more times. Hence matching `"john"`, `"john d."`, and `"john doe"` (`ignore.case = TRUE` takes care of the cases).

**Result:**

```
> names2
[1] "Third John"  "First John"  "Second John" "Third John"  "Third John"  "Second John"
```

Comment: I did not know the word boudry `"john(\\b|\\sd*)"` and it looks promising. I'll test it with other names I need to work as well and see if that solves problem #1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = c(Johnatan = "First John", johnnie = "Second John", John = "Third John")
temp[apply(X = sapply(names(temp),
                 function(x) grepl(pattern = x,
                                   x = names,
                                   ignore.case = TRUE)),
      MARGIN = 1,
      FUN = function(x) head(which(x), 1))]
#         John      Johnatan       johnnie          John          John       johnnie 
# "Third John"  "First John" "Second John"  "Third John"  "Third John" "Second John"
```

Comment: This obviously does the job, but in order to use it I have to digest your code. Too many new things there for me to understand it

Comment: great, thank you for this suggestion. Will test that in a sec.

Comment: d.b thanks again for the code - it work with the 3rd John when previous steps have been taken. Problem is I don't know how to extend it to a more general use and apply it to other names etc. But that's probably off topic in here. I think @useR approach (showing me to learn more about regex statememts), while it's not shortening all steps, might work better with other names (or words or any kind of text messiness I have to deal with)